# Task.Factory.New vs Task.Run vs async/await, best way to not block UI thread

Tags: c#

I need to make sure some of my code runs in the background and doesn't stop block the UI thread, and I thought I knew how to use Task.Factory.New, but as I read more and more, it seems that it doesn't always create a new thread but sometimes runs it on the UI thread if the thread pool thinks that's the way to go so now I am pretty confused over what to use to be safe that the method is not blocking the UI thread. I should also add that I don't need a return value from the method , I just need it to run asynchronously ( in the background ).

So what's the difference between these methods below and what is best to use to make sure it doesn't block the UI thread ?

And is it really true that Task.Factory.StartNew doesn't always create a thread that runs in the background and doesn't block the UI?

```
     public Form1()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));

        Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));

        Task<int> longRunningTask = LongRunningOperationAsync();
    }

    public async Task<int> LongRunningOperationAsync() // assume we return an int from this long running operation 
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Note, in your example you are **not blocking** UI thread with either. `Task.Run` is absolutely equal to `Task.Factory.StartNew` and simply a preffered way to start task with default options.  You are **not starting** `longRuningTask` (you have to use `Run`) either.  So your question is not really clear.

Comment: What is it that isn't really clear? I wanted to know what ways there is to use for not blocking the UI with threads/tasks/async and the code shows just some examples of how you can achieve this. There maybe is more ways that I don't know of and I got good answers of the difference between the methods used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two examples you give are pretty much the same and depend of the context you are using them on.

Tasks are a way to describe a packet of work with meta information to know about its state, synchronize multiple tasks, cancel them etc. The main idea about tasks and asynchronicity is that you don't have to care about "where" (on which thread) this unit of work is executed, it is performed asynchronously, that's all you need to know. So no worries for your UI-Thread, as long as you are working asynchronously, it won't be locked (that's one of the main improvements since Win8 and the async/await keywords, every UI Manipulation has to be async not to bloat the UI).

As for async&await, those are in fact syntactic sugar. In many simple cases, you don't need to care about the task itself, you just want the asynchronous computation *"do this and give me the answer when you have it"*.

```
int x = await ComputeXAsync(); //Returns a Task<int> which will be automatically unwrapped as an int
```

If you need to synchronize tasks, for example start multiple tasks in parallel and wait that all of them are done before continuing, you can't rely on the simple `await Task<int>` format, you then need to work with the task itself, its `Status` property and in this case the `Task.WaitAll(task[])` API.

Edit: I really recommend the chapter of JonSkeets Book C# in Depth (last edition). The Async/Await part is really well explained and will take you way further than any reading online will do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have 1 question : If I don't need to get an answer back from a method that runs in the background, I just need it to do something for me without blocking UI,  would you still use async/await or would you use Tasks and why?

Comment: When you see an await keyword, you can interpret it as "here the code block will be async executed. The method from where it is called returns right away and will be continued when the async call is done". So if your method does only this async call, it's exactly the behavior you wish to see.

Comment: Ok I understand, but as I said before, if I don't need an return answer or don't want to block the current code execution which await does( I don't mean the UI block ), then Task is better right? Because Task lets you perform the code in a different thread while the main code is still executed as normal if I understood this correctly.

Comment: I think you got it right, although your comment "Task is better" is misleading. Both cases use Tasks and the go hand in hand. In order to definie an asynchronous call, you will have to create and start a Task, and if you need to explicitely unwrap the result, you use the await keyword.

Answer (score 2):

> I should also add that I don't need a return value from the method

Beware of a common problem: just because you don't need a return value doesn't mean you shouldn't `await` the returned task. `await`ing the task provides you with exception information as well. The only time it's appropriate to ignore the returned task is when you don't care about the return value **and** you don't care about any exceptions the background work may raise (that is, you're OK with silently swallowing them).

In easily >99% of cases, the appropriate behavior *is* to `await` the task.

> So what's the difference between these methods below

`StartNew` is an outdated way to run code on a thread pool thread. [You should use `Run` instead of `StartNew`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). I describe why in painful detail on my blog, but the short answer is that `StartNew` does not understand `async` delegates and has inappropriate default options.

`async` is completely different. `Run` executes code on a thread pool thread, but `async` rewrites the code so that it doesn't need a thread while there's an asynchronous operation in progress. So, the `Run` example will block a thread pool thread for 1000ms in the `Thread.Sleep` call. The `async` example will run on the UI thread and then *not use the UI thread* for 1000ms in the `await Task.Delay` call.

> and what is best to use to make sure it doesn't block the UI thread?

Both `Task.Run` and `async` are appropriate in UI apps, depending on the nature of the background code.

If your code is asynchronous (usually all I/O-bound code), then you should use `async`/`await`. Note that imposing asynchrony "top-down" is hard. Don't think about "forcing code off the UI thread"; instead, identify the naturally-asynchronous parts of your system (DB, file, WebAPI calls, etc), change them to be `async` *at the lowest level*, and work *up* from there.

If your code is synchronous (CPU-bound), then you can use `Task.Run` if it takes too long to run on your UI thread.

> And is it really true that Task.Factory.StartNew doesn't always create a thread that runs in the background and doesn't block the UI?

`Run` always executes code on threads from the thread pool. The rules for `StartNew` are much more complex, but in your example example code, if `TaskScheduler.Current == TaskScheduler.Default`, then `StartNew` will also use a thread from the thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are actually the same. see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)

Well you can think of it as a task is something you want to be done.
A thread is something like a worker which does the task for you. So basically a threads helps you doing a task, but it doesn't return a value.

> a task does not create its own OS thread. Instead, tasks are executed by a TaskScheduler; the default scheduler simply runs on the ThreadPool.

[See Here](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-10-11/threads-vs-tasks/)

An example is. A remote request you can do as task, you want the job done but dont know when it will be. But a TCPListener for the server I would run as a thread, because it always needs to listen to the socket.

Like  Andreas Niedermair pointed out, you can also use longliving tasks with the `TaskCreationOptions`

Comment: There is a little chance for enforcement by using `TaskCreationOptions`, where you can go eg for `LongRunning`.

Comment: @Joerg : If you actually check what thread you are currently working in when performing first 2 tasks examples, is shows different threads than the main thread ( Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId ) , so somehow it seems that it creates a new thread when performing the tasks.

Comment: that is correct. because a task is run in threads. Compared to threads you don't manage them, because you just don't care! You want a job done asynchronously, not handle the lifecycle of the thread. So for UI things I mostly use task.

Comment: @Joerg : Thats true, and I maybe I have misunderstood the using of Task.Factory.StartNew, because it maybe is so that it always start working on a different thread than the UI but maybe it doesn't always create a NEW thread but uses the one that is available from the ThreadPool or something. Can that be the case?

Comment: Well the Threadpool provides the threads which can be used for working. I THINK it always creates a new thread, but dont nail me on that.